# Head component in magento 2

Tags: magento2, backend

how to add one more option in head component in sales order view page?

[image]
i check in layout and ui_component in magento sales module,there i not getting any exact idea about to edit.

```
  [![enter image description here][1]][1]

 <referenceBlock name="head.components">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="sales_page_head_components" template="Vnecoms_VendorsSales::page/js/components.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="sales_order_invoice.grid.container">
        <uiComponent name="vendor_sales_order_view_invoice_grid"/>
    </referenceBlock>
   <referenceBlock name="sales_order_creditmemo.grid.container">
        <uiComponent name="vendor_sales_order_view_creditmemo_grid"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="sales_order_shipment.grid.container">
        <uiComponent name="vendor_sales_order_view_shipment_grid"/>
    </referenceBlock>
```

please help me

Answer (score -1):

In di.xml

```
 <type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View">
     <plugin name="addNewButton" type="Vendor\MyModule\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View"/>
 </type>
```

In Vendor\MyModule\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View.php

```
public function beforeSetLayout(\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View $view)
{
    $message ='Are you sure you want to display this?';
    $url = '/vendormodule/controller/action/id/' . $view->getOrderId();


$view->addButton(
    'order_myaction',
    [
        'label' => __('My Custom Action'),
        'class' => 'customclass',
        'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}','{$url}')"
    ]
);


}
```

Comment: is there any other way????

Comment: @sam check my updated comment